# MobX sync observable update workaround for a select/de-select all checkbox

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mobx, mobx-react

I have a checkbox list which at its top has `Select All` checkbox. It is driven by an `observable array` of strings. When user checks on the `Select All` it should as it says `check` all checkboxes and on subsequent click it should unselect all. Pretty straight forward.

Some details on the state etc:

```
let arrayB = ['a','b','c'] // List coming from an API etc

let state = observable({
   arrayA: [],  // <-- nothing is checked by default
   get hasAllChecked() {
    return ( state.arrayA.length === arrayB.length )
  },
})
```

---

The issue is that I am curious about is in this handler for the checkbox list `onChange`:

```
if (!state.hasAllChecked) {
  removeChildren()
} else {
  removeChildren()
  addAllChildren()
}
```

At first glance you would ask why not refactor this to:

```
removeChildren() 
if (!state.hasAllChecked)
  addAllChildren()
```

Here is why and the steps to illustrate:

1. Checkbox is clear and nothing is checked. You click and all boxes are not checked.
2. So far everything is great. Now user clicks again on the `Deselect All` checkbox (same box just the label changes based on the `hasAllChecked` value)
3. Since we have no `if` now we go ahead and `remove` all items
4. Behind the scenes MobX updates the observable and now it is `false` since the two arrays are `NOT` equal
5. We now add all items and all checkboxes are clicked.

End result is nothing is de-selected since we removed all and then added all. Hence the need for that `else`.

**Is there a way to refactor this without doing the `else` and having `removeChildren()` twice in the code? Note that I want to avoid calculating array `difference` and add/remove needed/missing elements.**

Having it there almost necessitates the need of a comment right next to it with an explanation etc. I am probably missing either something simple or something fundamental with mobX etc.

Answer (score 0):

Current workaround I have found to simplify this is in the case of `lodash` (currently using it anyway) and `_.constant` or similar approach where you would do:

```
let hasAllChecked = _.constant(state.hasAllChecked)  // <-- freeze value

removeChildren() 
if (!state.hasAllChecked)
  addAllChildren()
```

Since this `"freezes"` the observable value and simplifies things.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure I understand your requirements, but here's a demonstration manipulating selections via a simple store. Hopefully this might help clarify things!

```js
const items = ["one", "two", "three", "four", "five"];

const store = {
    checked: [],

    checkAll() {
        this.checked.replace(items);
    },

    get hasAllChecked() {
      return this.checked.length === items.length;
    },

    isChecked(item) {
        return this.checked.includes(item);
    },

    selectItem(item) {
      this.isChecked(item) ? this.checked.remove(item) : this.checked.push(item)
    },

    uncheckAll() {
        this.checked.clear();
    }
};

decorate(store, {
    checked: observable,
    checkAll: action,
    selectItem: action,
    uncheckAll: action
});

const toggleSelectAll = () =>
    store.hasAllChecked ? store.uncheckAll() : store.checkAll();
```

[CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/unruffled-lederberg-uw3d3?fontsize=14).

The component consuming this would probably look something like:

```js
const renderCheckboxItem = (item, i) => {
    const checked = store.isChecked(item);
    return (
        <React.Fragment key={`item-${i}`}>
            <input
                name={`item-${item}`}
                type="checkbox"
                checked={checked}
                onChange={() => store.selectItem(item)}
            />
            <label htmlFor={`item-${item}`}>{item}</label>
        </React.Fragment>
    );
};

const renderItem = (item, i) => <li key={`selected-item-${i}`}>{item}</li>;

const Selector = observer(() => {
    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <form>
                {items.map(renderCheckboxItem)}
                <React.Fragment key="item-select-all">
                    <input
                        name="select-all"
                        type="checkbox"
                        onChange={toggleSelectAll}
                    />
                    <label htmlFor="select-all">Select all</label>
                </React.Fragment>
            </form>

            <p>Selected items:</p>
            <ul>{store.checked.map(renderItem)}</ul>
        </React.Fragment>
    );
});
```

In a more complex setting, I suspect you'd want to be tracking objects with ids rather than simple strings, so the solution would likely be more complex too. I think there's also a pretty strong case for not maintaining form state in MobX, but rather keeping it in component state and if other components require it, pushing the current list of selected items to the store (empty or otherwise).